# Disabling Nvidia driver completely

Tags: drivers, cmd.exe, windows-update, bsod, display-driver

My NVIDIA GPU got fried long ago and is no longer working. My PC is running on the default Intel Graphics driver. My PC works fine until it comes to updating windows. During any update, windows looks for the NVIDIA drivers and tries to reinstall the drivers, my PC crashes into BSOD stating various things like nvlddmkm.sys failure page fault in non pages area etc-. My GPU shows code 43 error in device manager, reason why i have disabled NVIDIA GPU from deice manager. But due to this issue I am not able to update to windows 11 because every time it looks for NVIDIA driver but since it is disabled and not working, pc crashes. Is there some way by which i can stop windows for looking for nvidia drivers during updates and skip nvidia drivers. I think there sure is a way i did contact Microsoft regarding this issue when i wanted to upgrade from windows 10 2004 to 20H2 but i forgot the way. they gave me a code to write in cmd that would stop windows from doing that. please help.

Comment: Instead of disabling it, have you tried using [DDU](https://www.guru3d.com/files-details/display-driver-uninstaller-download.html) to completely uninstall the NVIDIA drivers and packages?

Comment: Can you disable it in BIOS? If you can do this, Windows won't even know it exists and will not attempt to install drivers.

Comment: @fuzzydrawings no i have not done that, and yes this idea sounds good any idea on how to do that?

Comment: @DrZoo DDU only completely uninstalls the drivers right? but they problem is that windows will recognise the gpu and automatically try to reinstall the drivers which puts me back in the same position. in the end, i have to always boot into safe mode and disable NVIDIA gpu from device manager.

Comment: @Vega You can only access the BIOS menu by pressing a certain button when you first power on the computer. Usually it's something like ESC or F10 but the best way to find out is put your computer brand/model and "BIOS menu" into a search bar.

Comment: Why are you keeping it in the slot if it's dead? Either remove it from the slot or unplug the power cables from the card. If there is no power to it, there is nothing there from the motherboards point of view.

Comment: @DrZoo i am on a laptop, so that is not a option. Also i ran windows 11 update and before that i did a registry edit to stop windows from updating drivers, so no bsod but the update did not go through and rolled back in between.